# How to plot histogram of frequency of counts by every x time unit?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a really big set of data that I was able to sort of structure how I want with

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(time, np.arange(0, max(time), t))).sum()
```

where df is the full data (a pandas df), time is a column of data where every row is the next 0.00001 second, and t is a variable that contains the amount of time I want to group by --  let's say every 0.00005 seconds for example.

The df has several columns: countnum (basically the row number), time (timestamp), and value (the data value).

However, I don't know how to go about plotting this, so that the x-axis is time groups, and the y-axis is frequency. Everything I've tried has given me the x-axis as time without groups, or something completely wrong.

I'm sure this isn't that complicated, but Google hasn't been helpful

edit: here's some data

```
   Count #  Time (s)  Values (V)
0        1   0.00001       3.022
1        2   0.00002       3.018
2        3   0.00003       3.013
3        4   0.00004       3.003
4        5   0.00005       3.003
5        6   0.00006       3.013
6        7   0.00007       3.013
7        8   0.00008       3.013
8        9   0.00009       3.003
9       10   0.00010       2.998
```

looking for:

say there was another value in the sample set for time=0.00007

```
                                     x
  x           x          x           x
  x           x          x           x
0----0.00002-----0.00004-----0.00006-----0.00008
```

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of data? Sidenote, have you considered `pd.DataFrame.resample`? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

It may make your grouping into time bins easier.

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs sure I'll throw the top 10 in the question! and no, how would I go about using that for this case?

Comment: thank you. What would the y-axis be like? If you group into bins of 0.00005 sec, you'll end up with 5 values for each bin. But how do we aggregate or transform those to the y values you want? Currently you're aggregating using `sum`, but how does that relate to a "histogram of frequency of counts"?

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs the prompt I have is "divide your raw data into regular intervals of size t and count the number of events n in each interval. Make a frequency histogram. In other words, plot the number of times that you got n counts against n."

Comment: Makes sense. So we would expect not every bin to contain the same number of samples (or events)?

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs correct, just the majority happen to be evenly spaced

Comment: I don't understand the problem can't you just go with: `df.groupby(pd.cut(time, np.arange(0, max(time)+ 0.00001, 0.00005))).count()['Count #'].plot()`

Comment: @PaulBauriegel my mistake, not every data point is 0.00001s apart. some time stamps have several values

Comment: The suggested output is more like a histogram indeed. But your prompt says to plot "n counts against n". Are you sure?

Comment: In this case, what about: `time.hist(bins=np.arange(0, max(time), t))` :)

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs that's how i understood it to be... now i'm second guessing it :D unfortunately, i can't get a confirmation until two days from now, so i'm going to go with my gut for now

Answer (score 1):

Here is some more randomly generated sample data that might better illustrate the point.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "time": np.random.randint(1, 4, size=100).cumsum(),
    "values": np.random.rand(100)
})
t = 5
```

Note that the values column is not necessary for the plot. Only the timestamps dictate how many values appear in each bin. For reference:

```
>>> df["time"].values
array([  1,   4,   6,   7,   8,  11,  14,  15,  18,  20,  22,  23,  26,
        27,  28,  31,  32,  34,  36,  38,  39,  41,  44,  46,  48,  51,
        52,  54,  55,  58,  60,  61,  64,  66,  68,  71,  72,  74,  76,
        79,  80,  82,  83,  84,  87,  88,  90,  91,  93,  96,  99, 100,
       102, 103, 105, 106, 107, 110, 113, 114, 115, 116, 118, 121, 122,
       123, 124, 126, 127, 130, 133, 134, 135, 137, 139, 141, 143, 145,
       147, 150, 152, 154, 155, 158, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 169,
       172, 175, 176, 177, 179, 181, 183, 185, 187])
```

Another way to group them is to divide by `t`, then get the number of events in each group using [`GroupBy.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
group_sizes = df.groupby(df["time"] // t).size()
```

Here is where I get a bit confused, because the number of events in each group is discrete, and histograms typically bin continuous data. However, you could use a bar-chart that looks like a histogram.

First compute how many times each number of sample occurs with [`pd.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
data = group_sizes.value_counts().sort_index()
```

data:

```
1     1
2    16
3    17
4     4
dtype: int64
```

So: only a single bin in the original data has 1 data point. Most bins have either 2 or 3 events, and a few have 4. Finally plotting:

```
data.plot.bar(width=1)
```

[image: Frequency bar plot]

Alternative oneliner:

```
df["time"].floordiv(t).value_counts().value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar(width=1)
```

---

PS: [`pd.DataFrame.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) is useful in case your "time" data is already in proper format. For instance, via `pd.to_timedelta` or `pd.to_datetime`. You can then resample your data into bins of arbitrary timesteps in a very natural way. In your case, `df.resample("50 us").size()` would do the trick.

Comment: close, but not quite what i'm looking for. with the example data i gave, dividing by 0.00002s like you suggested, i get: 
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    2.0
4    2.0
5    2.0
6    3.0
7    4.0
8    4.0
9    4.0

now what i need is for all the numbers that are the same to go into the same "bar", and the x axis to be the time stamps still. so something like:

Comment: this isn't formatting right, i'll put it in the question